# How to create a function for repeated case_when

Tags: r

**Background**

I have a dataframe with a nested list

The list contains medical diagnoses. I want to convert these diagnoses into codes.

Each list will have one code extracted into a Primary diagnosis column, then the next diagnosis will be extracted into a secondary diagnosis column, then the third. Every time the diagnosis matches what is in the list, that element is removed from the list.

**The problem**

I have to repeat the case_when every time I iterate through the list and I would like to be able to refer to the list rather than repeat it each time

**An example:**

```
structure(list(myDx = list("Normal Study", c("There is Barretts with two things", 
"everywhere", " Four biopsies taken"
), c("Mitotic lesion", " Barretts", 
"Hiatus hernia", "THis was traversible", 
"but only just"), "Hiatus Hernia", c("Some Barrett's was seen", 
"There were no nodules"), c("HGD seen", 
"mitotic lesion"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**My code**

```
mydf<-mydf %>%
    mutate(
      PrimaryDiagnosisCode = map(
        mydx, ~ case_when(
          grepl("mitotic|emr|tumour", tolower(.x)) ~ "C159  -  Malignant neoplasm oesophagus, unspecified - Oesophagus - unspecified",
          grepl("barrett",tolower(.x),ignore.case=TRUE) ~  "K227  -  Barrett's oesophagus",
          grepl("hiatus",tolower(.x),ignore.case=TRUE) ~  "K449  -  Diaphragmatic hernia without obstruction or gangrene",
        TRUE ~ "other")
    ),
    mydx = map(
      mydx, ~ .x[!grepl("(mitotic|emr|tumour|dysplasia|hiatus|stricture|barrett|hiatus", tolower(.x),ignore.case=TRUE,perl=TRUE)]
    )
)
```

I have to repeat this for the secondDiagnosis and the ThirdDiagnosis (with a name change in mutate)

This gives me the output I want which is:

```
PrimaryDiagnosis     SecondDiagnosis      ThirdDiagnosis
K227
C159                    K227                K449
K449
K227
C159
```

What I am looking for:

```
 mydf<-mydf %>%
        mutate(
          PrimaryDiagnosisCode = map(
            mydx, ~ case_when(REFERENCE TO MY GREPS)
        ),
        mydx = map(
          mydx, ~ .x[!grepl("(mitotic|emr|tumour|dysplasia|hiatus|stricture|barrett|hiatus", tolower(.x),ignore.case=TRUE,perl=TRUE)]
        )
    )
```